# Walled gardens and Stack Overflow content

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

One of the greatest benefits of Stack Overflow is that it's not a walled garden. Content is accessible to everyone who searches for the answer to a question.

It is similar to what [Usenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) forums used to be back in the 1990s and early 2000s. People would post questions on those forums and volunteers would answer.

There were some great forums back in those days that I used a lot such as comp.lang.c++, however recently I've noticed a turn to people asking questions in [Slack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_(software)) channels related to the technology they are using.

There are Slack channels for C++, AWS, F#/.NET, etc., but the problem with this is:

1. They are walled gardens. If someone answers your question in there that information is not shared with the global community. In fact it's lost.
2. It relies on the that person being available to answer the question.

For example, I've used some niche libraries written in [F#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) and got answers directly from the author of that library in the relevant Slack channel, which is great for me, but the problem is that person who is an expert in that library won't be around forever, and will probably lose interest in a few years and stop being regularly on that Slack channel.

So my question is: Is there a way that a plugin can read data from these places and somehow integrate it with Stack Overflow?

Of course, this can also apply to other Stack Exchange sites as well.

Comment: A quick note regarding downvotes: here on Meta Stack Exchange, on questions requesting new features, voting [is used to signify agreement or disagreement with a given proposal](/help/whats-meta), so if your question gets downvoted, it may just mean that people disagree with your proposal, not necessarily that your question is bad for the site.

Comment: So you want to smash all these communities into one? The posts and questions would just get even *more* "lost". Please explain how you think this will be a benefit.

Comment: How do you envision this feature working? Would Stack Overflow clone the content of a private Slack channel into their database? How would SO secure copyright permissions from the original author? You'd also need each Slack channel admin to install some sort of plugin. How would the plugin identify the question? Whose account would be used to publish answers? Seems like it'd be easier for the authors of the Slack posts to just copy/paste their own content into a self-answered post using their regular accounts.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bad question in terms of the end result op wants. The implementation... Maybe but bringing in information from outside is... Well everything. And I guess information from private communities might have their own unique issues.

Comment: I thought [Usenet was completely destroyed in 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September).

Answer (score 12):

Walled gardens are walled gardens for a reason. While chat is underloved, it's good for stepping through an issue.

In many cases though - it's worth building on the knowledge you got elsewhere, using that as a starting point, researching more and posting a more fleshed out Q&A pair. One of my more annoying problems ended up being solved on a mailing list. I posted a working answer, others built on it and the knowledge is now out in the Commons.

If you can it's nice to give a mention to who helped, organic to an answer but it's not always an option if you don't remember - and it's also nice to ask/let them know if you can.

While software solves many problems you need human beings to actually look at the information, decide if it needs to be a new question or an answer to an existing one

So the plug in - or more specifically the interface is... Our users